# which security measures for asp.net mvc 3 app and WCF on a sql server 2008 db?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, sql-server-2008, wcf-security

how can I make my asp.net mvc 3 application 100 % secure. I am using a sql server 2008 db as a backend. I am also planning to use WCF to post data back to the db.

so my ideas sofar is using :
-wcf request throttling
-use the antiforgery token. 
The db has sensitive information so I dont want it to get compromised or accessed. What can i do make sure this is safe?
Am I missing some other issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use dynamic SQL
- Use an ORM
- Don't create your own authentication and authorization mechanism unless absolutely necessary. Try to use Forms Authentication if you can.
- Apply a global authorization filter to facilitate making sure your pages are locked down http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx
- Keep cookie use to a minimum (you can use session most of the time, really!) as they can increase the surface of exploitable entry points into your application
- Don't do stuff with your code that can get hacked easily, I have [posted](http://johnculviner.com/post/2011/06/22/Dont-trust-the-client-%28part-1%29.aspx) about some extremely simple exploits in the past
- Read and understand the [OWASP top 10 security exploits](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project)